# WORDLE clone - duplicate letter verification logic

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a WORDLE clone and I was following [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wak7iN4JZzU&t=1s)

If you neve played WORDLE before, it is a word guessing game. The word is 5 letters long. There are 3 types of verification in the game

1. The letter is not in the word - the background color turns dark.
2. The letter is in the word but in the incorrect position - the background color turns yellow.
3. ther letter is in the word and in the correct position - the background color turns green.

So far I've got most of the logic to work properly as I was following the video tutorial. However, I'm not entirely sure how to code the logic so that it checks if there's more than one of the same letter in the user input or not.

As for now, if the targetWord is THOSE, and the user input GEESE, then the 2 E's in that comes after the G will turn yellow and the last E turns green, but this is not correct since this is misleading the user that there are a total of 3 E's in the word instea of 1.

[my WORDLE clone game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mE8w.png)

Here's my code

```
/**
 * Get the information how many active tiles are there per guess.
 */
function getActiveTiles() {
    return gameArea.querySelectorAll('[data-state="active"]');
}

/**
 * Submits user's guess.
 */
function submitGuess() {
    let activeTiles = [...getActiveTiles()]

    if (activeTiles.length !== 5) {
        showAlert("Not enough letters");
        shakeTiles(activeTiles);
        return
    }

    let guess = activeTiles.reduce(function (word, tile) {
        return word + tile.dataset.letter
    }, "");

    if (!dictionary.includes(guess)) {
        showAlert("Not in word list");
        shakeTiles(activeTiles);
        return
    }

    stopGame();
    activeTiles.forEach(function (tile, index, array) {
        flipTile(tile, index, array, guess);
    });

}

/**
 * Flip the tiles after user have submitted their guess
 */
function flipTile(tile, index, array, guess) {
    let letter = tile.dataset.letter
    let key = keyboard.querySelector(`[data-key="${letter}"i]`)

    setTimeout(function () {
        tile.classList.add("flip")
    }, (index * FLIP_ANIMATION_DURATION) / 2)

    tile.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
        tile.classList.remove("flip");
        if (targetWord[index] === letter) { // if the letter is in the correct place
            tile.dataset.state = "correct";
            key.classList.add("correct");
        } else if (targetWord.includes(letter)) { // if the letter is in the word but in the incorrect place
            tile.dataset.state = "wrong-location";
            key.classList.add("wrong-location");
        } else {
            tile.dataset.state = "wrong"; // if the letter is not in the word 
            key.classList.add("wrong");
        }

        if (index === array.length - 1) {
            tile.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
                startGame();
                checkWinLose(guess, array);
            }, {
                once: true
            })
        }
    }, {
        once: true
    })
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Someone tried to post a solution in the comments of the video but it still doesn't really work as expected

They said to do as follows

```
let testVar = ""

/**
 * Submits user's guess.
 */
function submitGuess() {
    let activeTiles = [...getActiveTiles()]

    if (activeTiles.length !== 5) {
        showAlert("Not enough letters");
        shakeTiles(activeTiles);
        return
    }

    let guess = activeTiles.reduce(function (word, tile) {
        return word + tile.dataset.letter
    }, "");

    if (!dictionary.includes(guess)) {
        showAlert("Not in word list");
        shakeTiles(activeTiles);
        return
    }

    stopGame();
    activeTiles.forEach(function (tile, index, array) {
        flipTile(tile, index, array, guess);
    });
    testVar = "";

}

function flipTile(tile, index, array, guess) {
    let letter = tile.dataset.letter
    let key = keyboard.querySelector(`[data-key="${letter}"i]`)

    setTimeout(function () {
        tile.classList.add("flip")
    }, (index * FLIP_ANIMATION_DURATION) / 2)

    tile.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
        testVar += letter
        tile.classList.remove("flip");
        if (targetWord[index] === letter) { // if the letter is in the correct place
            tile.dataset.state = "correct";
            key.classList.add("correct");
        } else if (targetWord.includes(letter)) { // if the letter is in the word but in the incorrect place

        if (answer.split(letter).length < targetWord.split(letter).length) {
          tile.dataset.state = "wrong-location";
          key.classList.add("wrong-location");
          temp += letter;
        } else {
          tile.dataset.state = "wrong";
          key.classList.add("wrong");
        }

        } else {
            tile.dataset.state = "wrong"; // if the letter is not in the word 
            key.classList.add("wrong");
        }

        if (index === array.length - 1) {
            tile.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
                startGame();
                checkWinLose(guess, array);
            }, {
                once: true
            })
        }
    }, {
        once: true
    })
}
```

Comment: So you are stuck on trying to disallow duplicate letters in the guess? Or is that allowed in your version?

Comment: If they are allowed, there is an issue: _which_ letters in the guess do you mark as in the word but in the incorrect place when there are more letters in the guess than the target?

Comment: For reference, if you were not marking specific letters, you could use a variant of the Mastermind algorithm.
Loop through the letters in the target word and guess word.
For each pair, check if they are the same; if they are, remove them (use temporary strings or something) and increment the "correct" count.
Then, total the counts of each remaining letter and for each letter in the guess word counts take the minimum of the guess count and the target count, treating a letter not present in the target as 0. Total the values found to get the "in but in wrong place" count.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Thank you for your comment. However, I'm still super confused. I'm really new to JS and I think this might've been too advance for me

Comment: Well, to start with, what exactly are you trying to do? My comments apply no matter the programming language, as they are about behavior and algorithms.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes What I'm trying to do is 1. allow duplicate letters in the guess. 2. If the duplicate letters in the guess match the targetWord, then color it green if its in the correct position. 3. Then color the other duplicate letter in guess yellow if its in the incorrect position OR color the duplicate letter in the guess grey if the targetWord does not have any duplicate letters.

Comment: So what must happen if the guess has more of a letter than the target? For example, which of the 'E's should be highlighted yellow with a target of EARNS and a guess of GREEN? Simply the first one?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes yes, the first one would be suffice and the next E would be gray since there is only 1 E in the target